# event.currentTarget accumulates events on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Dynamically created content has a delete option. I capture the event via

```
function requestDeleteItem() {
  $(".list").on("click", ".fa-trash-alt", event => {
    const itemId = $(event.currentTarget)
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .attr("id");
    const itemName = $(event.currentTarget)
      .parent()
      .siblings("span.name")
      .text();  

  confirmDeleteItem(itemName, itemId);
  });
}
```

In the `confirmDeleteItem` function a confirmation button is generated and the AJAX call is made via JQuery.

The delete option for each item has an icon. I can click on the icon for multiple items and then click the confirm button on the final one and it will delete all previously clicked items, rather than just one.
I want to delete just the last clicked item. I'm thinking it has to do with the current event target and that it gets saved in memory, but i am not advanced enough to more.

Comment: I cannot see event.currentTarget anywhere being used in your code.

Comment: @connexo that was intentional for the sake over viewing pleasure. Added back in

Comment: `currentTarget` is `.list`, not `.fa-trash-alt`. You probably meant to use `event.target`. Also, you could simplify `itemId` to `$(event.target).closest('[id]').attr('id')`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts changing $(event.currentTarget) to $(event.target) does not fix the problem

Comment: `itemId` is an implicit global because you don't declare it with `var`, `let` or `const`. Try adding that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it was a mistake i made copying the code on here. It is the way you mentioned in my code

Comment: HTML would help, otherwise we don't really know what `.parent()` or `.parent().parent()` `.siblings()` really is, or if it's feasible, or if there's a better course of action.

Comment: @zer00ne ID and NAME get copied correctly. Id is a string of numbers, and name is the title of the element.

Comment: @Helle some OPs do not realize that they have overlooked something or was mistaken on how a method or property really works. You said, *'..but i am not advanced enough..."*. You should be aware that you are dealing with elements and their position within the DOM. A textual description is ok but most likely will not cover other aspects necessary for proper assessment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your `$(".list").on` event *outside* of `requestDeleteItem`.

What is happening is that every time you call requestDeleteItem() (to create a ajax button), you are also creating a handler for every list. Thus, your event handling code gets called over and over again when the button is clicked. Instead, when using event delegation, you only need to add the handler **once**, as it will pick up any buttons added later.

Here's a simplified code snippet that shows the correct behavior. Note how 
`$("#container").on('click'` is only called once.

```js
let num = 0;

const requestDeleteItem = () => {
  $("#container").append(`<button class="del">delete ${num}</button>`);
  num++;
}

$("#add").on('click', () => {
  requestDeleteItem();
});

$("#container").on('click', '.del', (e) => {
  console.log(`clicked on ${e.currentTarget.innerHTML}`);
})
```

```css
.del {
  display: block;
}

#container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=add>add button</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

For comparison, here's a **BAD** example that adds the event handler every time:

```js
let num = 0;

const requestDeleteItem = () => {
  $("#container").append(`<button class="del">delete ${num}</button>`);
  num++;
  $("#container").on('click', '.del', (e) => {
    console.log(`clicked on ${e.currentTarget.innerHTML}`);
  })
}

$("#add").on('click', () => {
  requestDeleteItem();
});
```

```css
.del {
  display: block;
}

#container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=add>add button</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```